# Do RNN solves the need for LSTM and/or multiple states in Deep Q-Learning?

Tags: deep-learning, recurrent-neural-networks, long-short-term-memory, q-learning

### Introduction

I am trying to setup a Deep Q-Learning agent. I have looked that the papers [Playing Atari with Deep Reinforcement Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.5602.pdf) as well as [Deep Recurrent Q-Learning for Partially Observable MDPs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.06527.pdf) as well as looking at the question [How does LSTM in deep reinforcement learning differ from experience replay?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/7721/how-does-lstm-in-deep-reinforcement-learning-differ-from-experience-replay).

#### Current setup

I currently take the current state of a game, not picture but rather the position of the agent, the way the agent is facing and some inventory items. I currently only feed state $S_t$ as at input to a 3 layer NN (1 input, 2 hidden, 3 output) to estimate the Q-values of each action.

The algorithm that I use is almost the same as the one used in [Playing Atari with Deep Reinforcement Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.5602.pdf), with the only difference that I do not train after each timestep but rather sample `mini_batch*T` at the end of each episode and train on that. Where `T` is the number of time-steps in that episode.

### The issue

At the current state, the agent do not learn within 100 00 episodes, which is about 100 00 * 512 training iterations. Making me consider that something is not working, this is where I realised that I do not consider any of the history of the previous steps.

What I currently struggle with is sending multiple time-steps-states to the NN. The reason for this is the complexity of how the game/program I am using. According to [Deep Recurrent Q-Learning for Partially Observable MDPs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.06527.pdf) LSTM could be a solution for this, however I would prefer to manually code a RNN rather than using an LSTM. Would not a RNN with something like the following structure have a chance of working?

[image: Simple RNN from pytroch-website.]

Also, as far as I know, RNN need the inputs to be fed in sequence and not randomly sampled?